# go build with multiple tags

Tags: go, build, tags

As seen [here](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints), go build accepts a "tags" flag that will include files that are "tagged," i.e.

```
// +build foo

package main

....
```

will be excluded from

```
go build
```

but included in

```
go build -tags=foo
```

Is there a way to include multiple tags? I.e.

```
go build -tags=foo && bar
```

Answer (score 22):

You should prefer including multiple tags in a comma separated list:

```
go build -tags=a,b
```

From [Go 1.13 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-command):

> The go build flag -tags now takes a comma-separated list of build
> tags, to allow for multiple tags in GOFLAGS. The space-separated form
> is deprecated but still recognized and will be maintained.

Comment: As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68360688 for versions >= 17   you should use `// go:build` directives where multiple tags are defined with their relation (which is a boolean expression). Example: `//go:build foo && bar` and `//go:build foo || bar`

Answer (score 16):

Multiple tags can be included in a space separated list:

```
go build -tags="foo bar"
```

Comment: I think the documention consists of the build help output, which shows multiple space separated words as the argument: `-tags 'tag list'`
 `a list of build tags to consider satisfied during the build.`

Answer (score -5):

you can build like this

> go build -tags=foo -tags=bar

Comment: This is incorrect, a build done in this way will have `tags = "bar"`, as the later tags overrides the former.

Comment: This results in: `go test: tags flag may be set only once`