# What's the difference between `//go:build` and `// +build` directives?

Tags: go, build, go-build

For example, https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/55b11dcdae8194618ad245a452849aa95e461114/cpu/cpu_gccgo_x86.go#L5-L9:

```golang
//go:build (386 || amd64 || amd64p32) && gccgo
// +build 386 amd64 amd64p32
// +build gccgo

package cpu
```

In my eyes, as a build tag, `// +build ...`  can work well. Why is `//go:build` still explicitly specified?

By the way, it is hard to find the documentation for `//go:build`, but it was easy for `// +build`, https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

#### Go 1.18

The new directive `//go:build` is now preferred and the toolchain will actively remove old directives; as mentioned in Go 1.18 release notes:

> In Go 1.18, `go fix` now removes the now-obsolete `// +build` lines in modules declaring go 1.18 or later in their go.mod files.

Due to the above, if you attempt to build a module with `go.mod` at 1.17 or lower that requires a dependency at 1.18 or above, the build may fail if the dependency is missing `// +build` lines.

#### Go 1.17

`//go:build` is the new conditional compilation directive used to specify [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints). It was introduced in Go 1.17.

It is meant to replace the old `// +build` directives; the use case is still same: it *"lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the package"*. The new syntax brings a few key improvements:

- consistency with other existing Go directives and pragmas, e.g. `//go:generate`
- support for standard boolean expression, e.g. `//go:build foo && bar`, whereas the old `// +build` comment has less intuitive syntax. For example AND was expressed with commas `// +build foo,bar` and OR with spaces `// +build foo bar`
- it's supported by `go fmt`, which will automatically fix incorrect placement of the directive in source files, thus avoiding [common mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214459/how-to-properly-use-build-tags/67946874) as not leaving a blank line between the directive and the package statement.

The two build directives **will coexist** over a few Go releases in order to ensure a smooth transition, as [outlined](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-gobuild.md#transition) in the relevant proposal document (in the quote below N is 17, emphasis mine):

> Go 1.N would start the transition. In Go 1.N:
>
> - Builds will start preferring `//go:build` lines for file selection. If there is no `//go:build` in a file, then any `// +build` lines still apply.
> - Builds will no longer fail if a Go file contains `//go:build` without `// +build`.
> - Builds will fail if a Go or assembly file contains `//go:build` too late in the file. Gofmt will move misplaced //go:build
>   and // +build lines to their proper location in the file.
> - `Gofmt` will format the expressions in `//go:build` lines using the same rules as for other Go boolean expressions (spaces around all `&&` and `||` operators).
> - **If a file contains only `// +build` lines, `gofmt` will add an equivalent `//go:build` line above them.**
> - **If a file contains both `//go:build` and `// +build` lines, `gofmt` will consider the `//go:build` the source of truth** and update the `// +build` lines to match, preserving compatibility with earlier versions of Go. `Gofmt` will also reject `//go:build` lines that are deemed too complex to convert into `// +build` format, although this situation will be rare. (Note the “If” at the start of this bullet. `Gofmt` will not add `// +build` lines to a file that only has  `//go:build`.)
> - The `buildtags` check in `go vet` will add support for `//go:build` constraints. **It will fail when a Go source file contains `//go:build` and `// +build` lines with different meanings**. If the check fails, one can run `gofmt -w`.
> - The `buildtags` check will also fail when a Go source file contains `//go:build` without `// +build` and its containing module has a go line listing a version before Go 1.N. If the check fails, one can add any `// +build` line and then run `gofmt -w`, which will replace it with the correct ones. Or one can bump the `go.mod` go version to Go 1.N.

More info about syntax changes: [Golang conditional compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646531/golang-conditional-compilation/67937234#67937234)