# How do I prevent gofmt adding `//go:build test`

Tags: go

In Go 1.17, `gofmt` automatically changes my files:

```
//go:build test
// +build test
```

I've uninstall Go 1.17 and re-installed 1.16, but the problem continues. How do I stop it?

I should say that I cannot use these tags, because the codegen we are using (which I cannot change) considers them an error and fails builds.

Comment: What's wrong with it? `go:build` is the new and preferred form. They will replace the build tags, so you should be thanking the go tool for helping the transition.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't. This is the new recommended more flexible format for build parameters.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/go1.17#build-lines: _"To aid in migration, `gofmt` now automatically synchronizes the two forms"_, and also

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68360688 , specifically to see why it is generally better than `+build`

Answer (score 1):

`gofmt` will only add the new format if it detects the old format; if it only sees the new format - it will not add the old format.

So, if you know you are building using go `1.17` (or later), you can drop the now legacy build constraint line:

```
// +build test
```

and migrate fully to the new build constraint format:

```
//go:build test
```

to just have a single build constraint line in your source.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to downgrade to Golang 1.16, but check that the links to tooling have been correctly changed back.