# Making widening integer conversions safely

Tags: go, type-conversion, integer-overflow

I need to make a few safe widening integer conversions – `uint32` to `uint` and `uint` to `uint64`, for example. I know it’s possible to achieve this with an explicit type conversion:

```
x := uint32(1) // suppose

y := uint(x)
```

But if `x`’s type changes later on, this will keep compiling while now doing the wrong thing.

```
x := int32(-1)

y := uint(x) // y is now 4294967295 or 18446744073709551615
```

```
x := uint64(4294967296)

y := uint(x) // y is now zero if uint is 32 bits
```

Is there an idiomatic way to perform an integer conversion that must either preserve the original value or fail to compile? The best I can come up with is to have a package of functions like this, which doesn’t seem worth it:

```
func Uint32ToUint(x uint32) uint {
    return uint(x)
}
```

Comment: That’s a hazard of changing a type without validating all uses of the value, signed and unsigned values have very different uses, so you need to fully validate how they are used. It’s also something that you almost never do so guarding against it seems like overkill

Comment: Is using generics an option?

Comment: If you wanted to, I suppose you could define something like `type SafeToConvertToUInt interface { uint32 | uint64 }` and then have just a single generic function `func ToUint[T SafeToConvertToUInt](x T) uint { return uint(x) }`. Dunno if that's any better than having a separate function for each such type, though.

Comment: @ruakh: Seems better to me! If you post that as an answer and nothing better comes up in the mandatory waiting period, I’ll accept it.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: (Yes.)

Comment: What @ruakh said was what I was going to suggest. That amounts to having a separate function for each type, but with the constraints, it will not generate the unsafe kind you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know of a very clean approach, but if there potentially a bunch of different types that you want to allow to be cast to `uint`, then instead of defining a separate function for each such cast, another option is to define an interface with the appropriate set of types, and then define a generic function that's defined only for types in that set:

```
type SafeToConvertToUInt interface {
    uint | uint32 | uint64
}

func ToUInt[T SafeToConvertToUInt](x T) uint {
    return uint(x)
}
```

[[playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/o1370JdXIJx)]

Comment: It should be noted that the width of `uint` can be either 64 bit or 32 bit, so the inclusion of `uint64` should be considered non-portable. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that Go has build tags to guard 32 bit vs 64 bit builds.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco: Yes, definitely. The OP alludes to that in the question, so I didn't think it needed clarifying; but maybe it's worth mentioning for the benefit of other readers?

Comment: @Ry-: The people have spoken. Can you un-accept this answer, so I can delete it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the generics approach to have compile-time guarantees about what types are accepted — with a small modification to make it more broadly useful — but that won't help when targeting different architectures. For that, you can use [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) so that the appropriate version of your function is compiled into the executable.

As an example, build for 32-bit linux:

```
//go:build linux && 386

func ConvertUint[T ~uint | ~uint32](x T) uint {
    return uint(x)
}
```

or build for 64-bit MacOS with Apple chip:

```
//go:build darwin && arm64

func ConvertUint[T ~uint | ~uint32 | ~uint64](x T) uint {
    return uint(x)
}
```

I used random build tags as an example. Your actual build conditions could be more complex than that. You can see which are Go's supported distributions, and have an idea of what build tags you might use with:

```
go tool dist list
```

When building with `go build`, the toolchain will pick up the `GOOS` and `GOARCH` environment variables and build the appropriate file. Otherwise you can pass the tags explicitly to the build command as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906316/go-build-with-multiple-tags).